# QuickFix and SessionSettings

Tags: quickfix

I am working with a python implementation of quickfix.
http://www.quickfixengine.org

I would like to set SocketConnectHost other than via the configuration '.ini' file, but have not discovered how to do this.

I have discovered that the SessionSettings class has a member SOCKET_CONNECT_HOST, but I don't seem able to 'set' this other than via the '.ini' file.

Nor can I see how to 'get' members individually either.

Printing a string representation of a SessionSettings instance gives a C++ ish reference to a location in memory and...

```
<quickfix.SessionSettings; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'FIX::SessionSettings' at 0x7f5a1c1333390>.
```

So it looks like the SessionSettings stuff is being handled in the C++ quickfix engine layer.

Can I get or set just SocketConnectHost from python?

Thanks,
Ben

Comment: There was no reason to tag quickfixn (c#) or quickfixj (java).  Users of those projects don't care about your Python problem.

Comment: @GrantBirchmeier OK, apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't speak for Python, but there's a `SessionSettings` instance you need to create a `SocketInitiator`.

Usually you would create this instance from the QuickFIX configuration file. After initializing it from the configuration file, you can change settings with the setter methods, eg `SessionSettings.setString(SessionID s, String key, String value)`. The key would be `SocketConnectHost` in your case.

Comment: Many thanks for your suggestion (much appreciated!). In Python too there is indeed a SessionSettings instance (see above), but no setter method along the lines of .setString(), .set() ... at least as far as I can see.

Comment: @abattia I'm looking at the C++ reference: `const Dictionary & get (const SessionID &) const throw ( ConfigError )`. Maybe get the dictionary for the session, and fiddle with the dictionary? [Reference](http://www.quickfixengine.org/quickfix/doc/html/class_f_i_x_1_1_session_settings.html)

Comment: @abattia What methods are available on the SessionSettings class you have?

Comment: SessionSettings has has(self, *args), get(self, *args), set(self, *args), size(self), getSessions(self) apparently ... but set() was not recognized.

Comment: @abattia Alas I know nothing about python... You don't have some sort of Python API reference for QuickFIX you can consult? I would guess (only a guess) that `get(self, *args)` and passing a `SessionID` for args would give you a `Dictionary`?